# How do you replace a word occurring on consecutive lines?

Tags: vim, text-editor, vim7.2

I usually either end up using `[range]%s/word/another_word/gc` or do it manually. I wonder if you guys use a different, perhaps a faster, way. Assume that I have vim 7.2.

Comment: in order to generalize your solution use the range ".,+1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `/word` plus enter to find the word; `cwanother` plus ESC to replace it the first time; then `n` to find the next occurrence of the word (possibly a few times if it appears several times on the line and I don't want to change every one), and then `.` to repeat the last change.

I use the range based global search-and-replace when the occurrences are scattered throughout an extensive range and it is really global search-and-replace that I want.

Answer (score 3):

`&` in command-mode repeats the previous search-and-replace command.  You can also do things like `3&` to repeat it over the next 3 lines.